# Use Adobe Flash/AIR VOIP in Winforms

Tags: winforms, air, flash, voip

Since there are no answers yet, I'm going to rewrite this question in hopes of an answer (I don't mind discussion, but I know SO is about Q&A).  It appears security checks/prompts make it unfeasible to use Flash Player.  With this in mind, the question still stands, but please answer based on experience using AIR.

I have a Winforms app written in C# that I need to add VOIP to.  I really like how well the Flash Player VOIP solution works, the AEC (echo cancel) is awesome.  I know they use Speex, but the implementation is still a lot of work even using Speex, so I'd like to use Adobe's solution directly in my app.

Has anyone done this?  What issues will I have?  A few I can think of:

IPC between AIR and Winforms app.  I assume this is easy and several options, including sockets/network, file i/o, maybe others.

Based on [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html)

> Content running in the AIR application sandbox does not need the
>   permission of the user to access the microphone

I don't think security warnings will be an issue?  I'm not sure what a sandbox is yet, but as long as my AIR app can run in this and still talk with my winforms app, then shouldn't be an issue.

I assume the voice capture including enhancements (AEC, NS, Speex, etc) are supported in AIR?

Are there any samples I can run that use voice capture in AIR?

Comment: Why aren't you using AIR if you are targeting a desktop app? You'd have access to the local filesystem and a few other benefits.

Comment: I don't know much about AIR.  Does that replace Flash Player for a desktop version?  So it would be the same Action Script code, but it runs in "AIR" instead of Flash Player?  I'm open to that if that makes it easier for IPC between my winforms app and AIR.  I don't want to rewrite my app in AIR though, so would still need IPC between the two.  My app also does screen sharing and other stuff that I wouldn't want to port/change.

Comment: AIR uses the Flash runtime. I was under the impression that you are yet to develop an application. If you already have a Flex based implementation then it's fine though converting a Flex app to an AIR app isn't really difficult at all. There are advantages to using AIR when you want to implement offline usage, native OS integration etc.

Comment: OK, I just read about it and installed the runtime.  The runtime download was around 13MB, which is 13 times my current app download, so I'd rather not use that unless it makes life a lot easier.  I don't need anything native, other than ICP to talk with my existing app, but I think JavaScript to FlashPlayer might be OK assuming I can resolve the security warning issue (I think that's the main thing).

Comment: Yes, getting around the (several) security sandboxes is a major pain-point when working with Flex applications (particularly something like yours where resources such as a webcam come into the picture).

Comment: Thanks for all the info, and it does seem like security checks will be a problem in the browser.  I am seeing now that I can host the ActiveX control directly and talk directly to ActionScript via C#.  Do you know if I would have the same security checks with that?  I'm going to add a link to my original post about this idea.

Comment: I don't think you can bypass user-interaction. E.g. when turning on the camera the *Privacy Dialog Box* is shown by the runtime and not your app (so you have no control over that bit). ActiveX control is simply a container (as is your browser) -- both of which depend on the Flash/Flex runtime to work.

Comment: "Runtime", so even with AIR I'll have the dialog box?  Everytime my app runs (and starts capture)?  Seems a bit excesive, if designed for a desktop app, since no other chat programs have that.

Comment: Yes. Not every time. The Flash Player Global preferences (or whatever it is called) can be made to remember your choice.